Limited to 5 RPM on Vertex AI
I'm looking for some help on this nebulous issue please.
I have this very simple script that invokes model generation on Vertex AI:
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel
import asyncio

PROJECT_ID = "MY_PROJECT"
vertexai.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location="us-central1")

async def _query_async(model: GenerativeModel, i: int) -> str:
    print(f"Sending request {i}")
    response = await model.generate_content_async("message")

    return response.text

async def run_pipeline_async() -> str:
    model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro-002")

    query_jobs = asyncio.gather(*[_query_async(model, i) for i in range(5)])
    query_responses = await query_jobs

    return query_responses

result = asyncio.run(run_pipeline_async())
print(result)

When I execute this, I get the following output:
Sending request 0
Sending request 1
Sending request 2
Sending request 3
Sending request 4

up until the exception:
Exception has occurred: ResourceExhausted
429 Online prediction request quota exceeded for gemini-1.5-pro. Please try again later with backoff.
grpc.aio._call.AioRpcError: <AioRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
    details = "Online prediction request quota exceeded for gemini-1.5-pro. Please try again later with backoff."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.70.170:443 {created_time:"2024-12-28T23:43:43.8287643+00:00", grpc_status:8, grpc_message:"Online prediction request quota exceeded for gemini-1.5-pro. Please try again later with backoff."}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "D:\Users\Harry\Code\PropScan\document\rate_limit_test.py", line 18, in _query_async
    response = await model.generate_content_async("message")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Harry\Code\PropScan\document\rate_limit_test.py", line 26, in run_pipeline_async
    query_responses = await query_jobs
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\Harry\Code\PropScan\document\rate_limit_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    result = asyncio.run(run_pipeline_async())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
google.api_core.exceptions.ResourceExhausted: 429 Online prediction request quota exceeded for gemini-1.5-pro. Please try again later with backoff.

This is consistent behaviour. The docs indicate that the default quota is 60 RPM, so I do not know why I am getting throttled to 5 RPM and cannot find any documentation explaining this. Some posts online suggested it might be because I am using a free trial account, but I have confirmed in the console that I am using a paid account (albeit there are remaining free credits.)

I am at a bit of a loss for where to go from here... The Quota and System Limits dashboard doesn't really help me at all (I think I am looking at the right thing here?)

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Your post does not show how you are setting up auth credentials. 1) Double-check that your authorization is using the correct billing account and that the Quota Project is set. 2) I would first implement Exponential Backoff and Retries so that your code can handle quota errors no matter the value. You will receive this error in the future if the service is over-tasked no matter your quota.
